# An operation was scaffolded that may result in the loss of data. Please review the migration for accuracy. happens after Update-database has no change

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations, ef-core-3.1

I performed an Update-database command and received the message that there were no changes and the database was up to date.

Then after subsequently issuing the add-migration command to create a new migration file I received this message in the console with an AlterColumn migration added to my migration file.

**An operation was scaffolded that may result in the loss of data. Please review the migration for accuracy.**

It appears as though there was a prior column alteration to change a column data type to a table in the database. But my migration was totally unrelated to the table or field change.

My question is why wouldn't that change have been picked up during the update-database command instead of a scaffold into my new migration file???

Maybe its my personal paranoia kicking in but I've never seen a change implemented by EF Core Code-First "after" Update-Database reports "no changes"

Answer (score 1):

> My question is why wouldn't that change have been picked up during the
> update-database command instead of a scaffold into my new migration
> file???

Because `update-database` applies the latest migration, not the other way around. You make some changes, run `add-migration XXXXX` which instructs EF to find any changes (using your context snapshot) and make a migration file. Nothing happens to the database until you apply the migration using `update-database`. If you make any more model/schema changes before applying the migration to the database, they won't be added to the pending migration automatically.